# Modifying Avada WordPress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to modify the Avada WordPress Theme. It doesn't seem to write header tags in H1 so I've been looking through the code in /themes/Avada/ to see if I can modify it myself.

I've looked in these files: header.php, page.php, index.php and I can't seem to find anything with the headers.

Looking at their page.php

```
<div class="post-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php fusion_link_pages(); ?>
        </div>
```

Does anyone know where the_content(); calls from?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the_content is WordPress core function.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

Answer (score 1):

You can change the header tags for posts in the file single.php.

You need to look for this code:

```
avada_render_post_title( $post->ID, false, '', '2' )
```

And change the 2 to a 1 (which represents the H1) tag.

```
avada_render_post_title( $post->ID, false, '', '1' )
```

Now your posts title should appear using the H1 tag.

Source: [Avada SEO](https://www.patchesoft.com/improve-avada-seo/)